# Torchvision ImageFolder "Could not find any class folder"

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

The code below

```
plastic_train_image_folder = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(plastic_dir, transform=transforms)
```

throws the following error:

> Could not find any any class folder in /Users/username/Documents/Jupyter/archive/Garbage classification/Garbage classification/plastic.

Yet, there are files there. The code below prints `482`.

```
list_plastic = os.listdir(plastic_dir) 
number_files_plastic = len(list_plastic)
print(number_files_plastic)
```

Why is this error happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/datasets.html#imagefolder), the `ImageFolder` class expects images to be within directories, one for each class of interest:

> A generic data loader where the images are arranged in this way:
>
> ```
> root/dog/xxx.png
> root/dog/xxy.png
> root/dog/xxz.png
>
> root/cat/123.png
> root/cat/nsdf3.png
> root/cat/asd932_.png
> ```

Your images are probably in the root directory, which is not the way it is expecting, hence the [error](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/7947fc8fb38b1d3a2aca03f22a2e6a3caa63f2a0/torchvision/datasets/folder.py#L35-L42).

Comment: So basically your images should be stored in a nested folder

Answer (score 0):

When you get it the path, it makes sure that there ia a directory in it:

```
def find_classes(directory: str) -> Tuple[List[str], Dict[str, int]]:
"""Finds the class folders in a dataset.

See :class:`DatasetFolder` for details.
"""
classes = sorted(entry.name for entry in os.scandir(directory) if entry.is_dir())
if not classes:
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Couldn't find any class folder in {directory}.")

class_to_idx = {cls_name: i for i, cls_name in enumerate(classes)}
return classes, class_to_idx
```

- So if your dataset is for exemple in /kaggle/dataset/women-clothes
  then yo want to it it /kaggle/dataset as a path directory and not /kaggle/dataset/dataset/women-clothes.